# Can't create TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE column in postgres due to SyntaxError

Tags: python, postgresql, ddl

I would like to create a table in postgres by running a DDL query using python, however I get a Syntax Error.

My code:

```
query = """CREATE TABLE data
(
    fire_date_utc TIMESTAMP,
    date_local  TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
    date_precision  TEXT
);

"""

with db.connect() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.execute(query)
```

The error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 22:     date_local  TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
```

I read somewhere that I should enable this feature first in postgres, which I did by running `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";` but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried ``WITH TIME ZONE`` instead of ``WITH TIMEZONE``?

Comment: What does `uuid-ossp` have to do with timestamp(z) types?

Answer (score 3):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) it has to be:

```
date_local  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
```

(note that `time zone` are two words)

Alternatively you can use `timestamptz` as the data type name.